# Issue with Combobox Selection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpf-controls, expression-blend

I am getting below random crash when I try to change the selection of a combo box in my WPF based application.

Please revert back to me if any one have any idea.

Also See this:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1660886/system-windows-controls-combobox-coerceisselectionboxhighlighted-bug

But I didn't find any solution for this or way out. Thanks!

XAML Code:

```
 <telerik:GridViewDataColumn
                                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding OriginItem.CompleteName}"
                                            Header="Portion"
                                            IsReadOnly="False">
                                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <ComboBox
                                                        DisplayMemberPath="CompleteName"
                                                        ItemsSource="{Binding ExtrasDistributionViewModel.CalculationViewModel.SettingsViewModel.OriginItemViewModels}"
                                                        SelectedItem="{Binding OriginItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>

Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Stacktrace:
   at System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.CoerceIsSelectionBoxHighlighted(Object o, Object value)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.ProcessCoerceValue(DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EntryIndex& entryIndex, Int32& targetIndex, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& oldEntry, Object& oldValue, Object baseValue, Object controlValue, CoerceValueCallback coerceValueCallback, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, Boolean skipBaseValueChecks)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.CoerceValue(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.OnIsDropDownOpenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.set_IsDropDownOpen(Boolean value)
   at Andritz.PreCalc.App.AppBootstrapper.TextBox_GotFocus(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in E:\Andritz\Precalc\Phase2-Austria\precalc\Andritz.PreCalc\Andritz.PreCalc.App\AppBootstrapper.cs:line 661
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.IsFocused_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyPropertyKey key, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.OnFocusedElementChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(DependencyObject element, IInputElement value)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Focus()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem.OnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.FireOnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RemoveVisualChild(Visual child)
   at System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.DisconnectChild(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.Clear()
   at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.ClearInternal()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.ClearChildren()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.EnsureEmptyChildren(FrameworkElement logicalParent)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.OnItemsChangedInternal(Object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.OnItemsChanged(Object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.OnRefresh()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList`1.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, Type managerType)
   at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.SetCollectionView(CollectionView view)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.SetItemsSource(IEnumerable value, Func`2 GetSourceItem)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnDataContextChanged(DependencyObject contextElement)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.HandlePropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependentList.InvalidateDependents(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs sourceArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateTreeDependentProperty(TreeChangeInfo info, DependencyObject d, FrameworkObject& fo, DependencyProperty dp, FrameworkPropertyMetadata fMetadata, Style selfStyle, Style selfThemeStyle, ChildRecord& childRecord, Boolean isChildRecordValid, Boolean hasStyleChanged, Boolean isSelfInheritanceParent)
   at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateTreeDependentProperties(TreeChangeInfo info, FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style selfStyle, Style selfThemeStyle, ChildRecord& childRecord, Boolean isChildRecordValid, Boolean hasStyleChanged, Boolean isSelfInheritanceParent)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateTreeDependentProperties(TreeChangeInfo parentTreeState, Boolean isSelfInheritanceParent)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorChangedInternal(TreeChangeInfo parentTreeState)
   at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnAncestorChanged(DependencyObject d, TreeChangeInfo info, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.StartWalk(DependencyObject startNode, Boolean skipStartNode)
   at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1.StartWalk(DependencyObject startNode, Boolean skipStartNode)
   at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateOnTreeChange(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyObject parent, Boolean isAddOperation)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.FireOnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RemoveVisualChild(Visual child)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.set_TemplateChild(UIElement value)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ClearGeneratedSubTree(HybridDictionary[] instanceData, FrameworkElement feContainer, FrameworkContentElement fceContainer, FrameworkTemplate oldFrameworkTemplate)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.DoTemplateInvalidations(FrameworkElement feContainer, FrameworkTemplate oldFrameworkTemplate)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.OnTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.OnContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateDependents(Style ownerStyle, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate, DependencyObject container, DependencyProperty dp, FrugalStructList`1& dependents, Boolean invalidateOnlyContainer)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.OnTriggerSourcePropertyInvalidated(Style ownerStyle, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate, DependencyObject container, DependencyProperty dp, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs changedArgs, Boolean invalidateOnlyContainer, FrugalStructList`1& triggerSourceRecordFromChildIndex, FrugalMap& propertyTriggersWithActions, Int32 sourceChildIndex)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewCell.ResetEditor()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewCell.RaiseCellEditEndedEvent(GridViewEditAction editAction)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewDataControl.PerformCellEditEnded(GridViewCell currentCell)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewDataControl.CommitCellEdit(GridViewCell currentCell, Boolean isLeavingRow)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewDataControl.CommitEdit()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewDataControl.EndEditAccordingToLostFocusAction()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewCell.HandlePendingEdit(UIElement focusedElement)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewCell.HandlePendingEditOnLostFocus()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewCell.OnEditorLostFocus(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.IsFocused_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.ClearValueCommon(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.ClearValue(DependencyPropertyKey key)
   at System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.OnFocusedElementChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at Andritz.Core.Controls.AGRibbonWindow.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(DependencyObject element, IInputElement value)
   at System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(DependencyObject element, Boolean validate)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(Object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.TryChangeFocus(DependencyObject newFocus, IKeyboardInputProvider keyboardInputProvider, Boolean askOld, Boolean askNew, Boolean forceToNullIfFailed)
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(DependencyObject focus, Boolean askOld, Boolean askNew, Boolean forceToNullIfFailed)
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.ReevaluateFocusCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Comment: Did you try the workaround provided in given link ?

Comment: There is no help to get without providing some code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: At least show us some code `XAML` and the `ViewModel`.

Comment: Did you try .NET Framework 4.6.2? Is the problem fixed in it?

Comment: I have just checked .Net Framework version and it's 4.6.1 installed with VS 2015.

Comment: I have uploaded XAML Code.

Comment: When I see "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." it is usually due to a null being passed somewhere your not expecting or trapping. Other than that code would be needed to reproduce the issue.